# Javascript not working after for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have written code to upload resized photos. Here is the html form for that:

```
<form action="aa.php"  method="post"  id="uploadImageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="fileToUploadId" name="fileToUpload[]" accept="image/jpeg, image/png"  multiple />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

On submit I'm running this JavaScript:

```
$('#uploadImageForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ds = [];
    var files = document.getElementById("fileToUploadId").files;
    for (var i in files) {

            if (typeof files[i] !== 'object') return false;
            resize.photo(files[i], 1200, 'file', function (resizedFile) {

                var resizedSize = resizedFile.size;
                ds.push(resizedFile);
            });  
            alert('for loop working'); //getting executed for each itteration 
    }

    alert('final alert'); //not getting executed
    console.log(ds);
});
```

But the code after the for loop doesn't get executed. The alert 'for loop working' for number of photos is showing as expected, but not 'final alert'.

Please note that the photo resizing happens here as expected and there are some script files i didn't included here. However there are no errors in the console.
I have run the code in chrome and firefox and both gives the same output.

One last thing is since I'm running this JavaScript on submit, the page does not go to `aa.php` as expected.

Comment: You are using `return`. use `continue`

Comment: You would use `return` if you did a jquery `$.each` - as it's a javascript `for`, you skip to the next item with `continue`.

Comment: Or you could flip the `if` condition and not use `return` or `continue`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just for clarification, why did it get 'break' even when I'm adding images? i.e if I added two images, it runs the loop twice and then got break. is it because a some feature of document.getElementById("fileToUploadId").files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function returns, it doesn't continue executing the rest of the code. Take a look at this line:

```
if (typeof files[i] !== 'object') return false;
```

Here you return the whole function, which terminates its execution. Try using `continue` statement instead, which will stop the current iteration and go to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

If `if (typeof files[i] !== 'object') return false;` ever gets triggered, it will stop the execution of your function, which means `alert('final alert');` never occurs.